# Trouble to install docker on my centos 8 VM

Tags: docker, yum, centos-8

My dev machine is a CentOS 8 VM, and I'm trying to install docker on it, so I can locally create docker images. I'm basically following the docker tutorial here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/

I added the docker repo and I needed to disable some packages because there were conflicts. But now I'm stuck at this part:

`$ sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

with the following error message:

```
Running transaction check
No available modular metadata for modular package 'container-selinux-2:2.155.0-1.module_el8.3.0+699+d61d9c41.noarch', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'fuse-overlayfs-1.3.0-2.module_el8.3.0+699+d61d9c41.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'libslirp-4.3.1-1.module_el8.3.0+475+c50ce30b.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
No available modular metadata for modular package 'slirp4netns-1.1.8-1.module_el8.3.0+699+d61d9c41.x86_64', it cannot be installed on the system
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: No available modular metadata for modular package
```

I tried `$ sudo dnf clean all` and `$ sudo yum clean packages` with no avail.

I'm not super familiar with yum and CentOS, so maybe I'm missing something trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issues was that I had disabled `container-tools` with `sudo dnf -y module enable container-tools`. Because it was creating issues with conflicting versions when I tried to install docker. I had to re-enable `container-tools` and then install the docker packages with `sudo dnf install docker-ce --nobest` critical here was to use the `--nobest` option to ignore certain conflicts.